# How do I limit the amount of digits accepted from the user?

Tags: c++

I currently have this and I can't seem to make my `else` work so the whole program doesn't limit the input successfully. (Sorry for my English I speak French).

```cpp
cout << "Veuillez entrer votre nombre de 6 chiffres : ";
cin >> val;

if (val < 100000);
{
    cout << "Erreur! Veuillez recommencez avec un nombre a 6 chiffres. " << endl << endl;
    return main();
}
if (val > 999999);
{
    cout << "Erreur! Veuillez recommencez avec un nombre a 6 chiffres. " << endl << endl;
    return main();
}
else 
    if
    {
        nb1 = val / 100000 % 10;
        cout << nb1;
    }
```

Comment: Side notes: [Never call `main`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3). It is intended to be called by the system and could have all manner of hidden program set-up code bolted on. Usually behaves as expected on a desktop system, but there are no guarantees. Best to just not do it. Never recurse based on user input. Be it by malice or idiocy, users will repeatedly input bad values and run the program out of Automatic Storage, likely causing a stack overflow and causing the program to fail in strange and wonderful ways. Use a loop instead.

Comment: Use `to_string(abs(num)).size()` to check, or in the input request it as string and check it, then convert it to an integer

Comment: @Muaath Converting to a string and then converting back would not be as efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a semicolon between the `)` and `{` of an `if` statement creates an empty `if` statement body, followed by an unconditional block, which is not what you want.

To check if a number has more than a certain number of digits, try comparing against **negative** 999999 instead.

The code should be made shorter by using logical operators instead of 2 separate `if` statements.

Lastly, you should not recurse into `main()`. Use `goto` instead.

**Corrected Code:**

```
retry:
cout << "Veuillez entrer votre nombre de 6 chiffres : ";
cin >> val;
if (val < -999999 || val > 999999) // Note the ; has been removed
{
    cout << "Erreur! Veuillez recommencez avec un nombre a 6 chiffres. " << endl << endl;
    goto retry;
}
nb1 = val / 100000 % 10;
cout << nb1;
```

Alternatively, you could use the `abs()` function (use `#include <cstdlib>`):

```
if (abs(val) > 999999)
{
    cout << "Erreur! Veuillez recommencez avec un nombre a 6 chiffres. " << endl << endl;
    goto retry:
}
nb1 = val / 100000 % 10;
cout << nb1;
```

Comment: Rather than using `goto`, put the validation code into a forever loop and put that loop in a function. Return from the function when valid input has been received. Now you have a reusable function (even more reusable if you pass the threshold in as a parameter) and don't have the nigh-impossible task of getting the `goto` through a code review.

Comment: @user4581301 Or the validation code could go in a forever loop and `break` if input is valid and `continue` if the input is invalid.